# Error 400 while using StringTrimmerEditor in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

We are using Spring MVC 3.2.3.RELEASE (annotations) with google app engine 1.8.0.

We added a StringTrimmerEditor for converting blank strings from form as null values and it is working fine, but as a side effect, all methods which use @RequestParams in controllers are expecting all the @RequestParams to be populated, otherwise they are throwing http error 400. We tried with different @RequestParam settings like (required=false) and (defaultValue="some value"), but it is not working.

here is how we are using it

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerSetup
{
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder ( WebDataBinder binder )
    {
        StringTrimmerEditor stringtrimmer = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringtrimmer);

    }
}
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addreportitems", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEditForm(@ModelAttribute DCReport dcReport,
            @ModelAttribute("loggedInEmployee") Employee someEmployee,
            @RequestParam Integer someInteger,
            Model m) {
....
}
```

If we dont put someInteger in form, we get an error 
**Error 400 Required Integer parameter 'someInteger' is not present**

If we remove StringTrimmer, it works perfectly fine, are we missing something here? Thanks very much in advance for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

The following is working for me:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public String renderFoo(@RequestParam(required=false) String bar) {
    return bar;
}
```

You must have made mistake somewhere when you were testing with `required=false`.